# Feedback on edit rejection: big change, but same intent (?)

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

Another `why was my edit rejected` question... :\

Edit in question: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11306917
<sub>Question: [Echo a multi dimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11822238/php-how-to-echo-a-multi-dimensional-array)</sub>

The main point of my edit was to make the post more applicable to future users, by shortening and simplifying it.  However, the edit got rejected:

> This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner.

(x2)

> This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.

(x1)

---

The original question asks how to echo (PHP) a multidimensional array, giving a (large) example, and a bunch of extra info (now superflous, as it has a great answer, and future comers no longer need to see all this info).

My edit re-phrased the question, and replaced his huge case-specific example with a more generic small example.

I'd like feedback on why this edit was rejected, and whether edits like this are acceptable.

Comment: I like the general idea of what you're doing but I would *not* have changed the names of the array entries, because it makes the answers difficult to understand clearly. As most, I'd keep the original structure of the array and filter down the number of fields -- keep `nick` and maybe one other field (like `ping`) to make it obvious that it's an array. that said, I find it very unlikely (as a practical matter) that such a huge edit would ever pass edit-review. As a >2K user, I would probably just make the edit and comment inviting the OP to revert, but you don't have that option, obviously.

Comment: Ok, yeah - that makes sense.  If you'd like, you could make the edit, with the comment.  As you said, I don't have that capability, as I'm not 2k.  (yet :-) )  I agree that, in hindsight, such a large edit, especially to a question, would probably never get past review.

Answer (score 3):

As commented by @apsillers, your change makes the answers more difficult to understand and therefore this edit does not improve the overall quality of the post. In particular case, the user that posted the original question, seems to be no longer active on SO (Last seen Sep 30 '12 at 2:09), so personally I would be hesitant to make such a large edit as the original author is unlikely to get notified and review the change.

Comment: Quite right as far as the edit size goes.  And I agree that changing the names of the array columns would probably make it more difficult to understand.  However, I think that if the column names were to be kept the same (probably just take two - say `nick` and maybe `ping`), the edit would make the question *far* easier to understand, without hurting the answers.  Thoughts?